DTO, ORM-entities and ElasticSearch
I'm trying to make a complex entity (Product), which includes many child entities:

main category
categories (array)
main unit of measurement
prices with links to currency, price type, unit of measurement (collection with nested entities).
etc.

I want also to use ElasticSearch for fast search in this structure, fast loading of catalog pages and for implementation of catalog filters.
The manager can create or edit products in the admin panel. Or he can upload data using the Symfony command. After any changes, partial or full data population in ElasticSearch occurs.
I have already written all this code to populate ElasticSearch index. I also have the ORM-resource, and the frontend is currently working with it. I have a DTO entity that is filled with data from Elastic, or can be created based on an ORM entity (I can also write code to do reverse operation, but it seems that I can't do this with the normalizer, since it gives some errors that the embedded resources must be iri-urls).
The data structure in ElasticSearch almost completely repeats the structure of the ORM entity, so I don't think it's appropriate to use several endpoints for the same actions (get / getCollection). In addition, the front-end developer should not think about which method to use to extract the Product, from Doctrine or from Elastic, this data is identical and it is not the front-end developer who should decide which is better to use in which case.
But ultimately, the site visitor should receive data from ElasticSearch. From the scattered examples in the documentation, I do not understand how to correctly build the architecture of my solution. And all attempts to do something end with errors related, for example, to incorrect serialization or some problems with missing jsonld-identifiers.
Is it possible to see somewhere a correct and complete example of creating an application where one complex entity (with sub-tables in doctrine, but it only one document in elastic) is represented as an ORM model, an index in ElasticSearch.
I can't also understand, for example, how to publish a complex DTO entity as a resource, and how to map it with an ORM entity. So that it would be possible to use orm-filters and paginator.
Although the documentation says that the concept is such that it is better not to use ORM entities as resources, I did not find any example in the documentation on how to publish DTO as a resource and then link it with ORM (don’t forget about filters, sorting and pagination). If you write all this code by hand, then there is no point in using the ApiPlatform at all.
I tried to make some Processors. I made a separate resource, but a can't fill all data properly with jsonld-identifiers. I couldn't understand how to create processor with some condition, to get data from ORM or from Elastic, to pass filters to datasource, to use pagination.
